# Python Code to combine duplicated element

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a list with duplicated some of element. And i need to combine some element based on the other duplicated element.

Example input:

```
[
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', 4),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', 1),
('Sig: 3326', '10.3.5.0', 7),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.1', 3),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.1', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.2', 5),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.2', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 2),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 1),
('Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.34', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.34', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.34', 1),
('Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.42', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.42', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.43', 2)
]
```

What the goal is like this:

```
[
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', 6),
('Sig: 3326', '10.3.5.0', 7),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.1', 4),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.2', 6),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 5),
('Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.34', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.34', 2),
('Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.42', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.42', 1),
('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.43', 2)
]
```

Is there any simple python code to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
 from itertools import groupby

l = [('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', '4'), ('Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', '1')...]

def tuples_sum(iterable):
  return list(iterable[0][:-1]) + [sum(int(i[-1]) for i in iterable)]

for i, j in groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
  print(tuples_sum(list(j)))
```

which gives:

```
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.0', 6]
['Sig: 3326', '10.3.5.0', 7]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.1', 4]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.2', 6]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.4', 5]
['Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.34', 1]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.34', 2]
['Sig: 0559', '10.3.5.42', 1]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.42', 1]
['Sig: 7126', '10.3.5.43', 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're grouping by the first two columns:

```
import itertools

grouping = itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda i: (i[0], i[1]))
summer = lambda group: sum(i[2] for i in group))
result = [(a, b, summer(group)) for (a, b), group in grouping]
```

- [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

If your input is not sorted by the grouping key, you need to sort it first:

```
import itertools

grouper = lambda item: (item[0], item[1])
data.sort(key=grouper)
grouping = itertools.groupby(data, key=grouper)

summer = lambda group: sum(i[2] for i in group)

result = [(a, b, summer(group)) for (a, b), group in grouping]
```

Comment: this would require sorting I think

Comment: The desired output doesn't suggest that any additional sorting is needed.

Comment: No, he wants not to eliminate duplicates, but to group by first two columns and accumulate a sum of the third for each group.

Comment: my bad, 3rd column was a number. Nice explaination btw. regards.

Comment: @SusiloBambangYudhoyono: removed the conversions.